# (git) How to merge all revision from doesn't existing branch into other branch?

Tags: git, merge

I have 3 branch in my git repo: **master**, **stand** and **develop**. For each feature i create new brach from **develop**.
After feature done, i'll merge it branch into **develop** (with *--no-ff* option).

For example, i have 3 feature (**f1**, **f2**, **f3**) merged branches in **develop**, and i removed **f1**, **f2**, **f3** (or it was created on another machine and developer doesn't pushed it into origin repo) after merging into **develop**.
And now i want to "put" **f1** and **f3** to **stand** branch (it have more than one commit in it and i can't use *cherry-pick*) what should i do?

Sure, i can create *cherry-pick* script for revision range merging, but maybe, i have a better way to merge it (by old branch name, or something else).

```
my repo:
develop          ---
               /
stand      ---
          /
master ---

feature branches:
          f1   f2   f3
         /  \ /  \ /  \
develop ----------------

i want:  f1   f2   f3
develop ----------------       
stand   -----    -------
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the branches anymore, luckily you used `--no-ff` so they can be recovered.  Look in gitk and find the SHA1 of the last commit before the merge commit on `develop` for feature 1.  Then to get it back just do:

```
git branch f1 SHA1
```

Then to put them on `stand`, do:

```
git rebase --onto stand develop f1
git checkout stand
git merge f1

git rebase --onto stand develop f3
git checkout stand
git merge f3
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. One more question: if i created branch f3 on develop after someone commit anything, it will merged too?

Comment: This particular method is only going to merge the changes actually made after `f3` branched off.  It won't pull in `f2`, for example.  There are other ways to pull it in if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cherry-pick the merge commits (created after merging two branches), which theoretically should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, i had read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch) topic , but i want a little something: just tell git "hey, some times ago i had branch with name f1, but now i merged it into develop and removed it. now, please, transfer all affected by f1 changes from develop into stand."

Comment: @Alexey Kutuzov Hold on, "removed it"? Then you're stuck with cherry-picking, aren't you? Were you looking for some way to recover the branches from deleted history?

Comment: @rubenvb, i'm really sorry - question was not correct (fixed now). Sure, i haven't branches any more.

Comment: Still, the merge commit in your "develop" branch should still be there, although I frankly don't have any first-hand experience with this particular situation. Try to find the merge commit with the graphical `gitk` utility.

Comment: Yep, _gitk_ still shown branches correctly. I think that _gitk_ can found info about that branches (because it's no fast-forwarded) we can do it too. But i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. create branch `f1_cpy` (on `f1`) and branch `f3_cpy` (on `f3`), these are the two copies which you will move/apply;
2. checkout to `f1_cpy`, rebase it to `stand` and then merge it to `stand`;
3. checkout to `f3_cpy`, rebase it to `stand` (which now includes `f1_cpy`) and then merge `f3_cpy` to `stand`.

---

This is in practice like cherry-picking, but maybe simpler to understand and manage/use.

The use of copy-branches is so you don't destroy your real history **when** something goes wrong.
If you do not use copy-branches and and end up loosing precious history... take a deep breath and dive into `git reflog`.
But **do** use copies, so you can play around at will.

Juggling knives is only awesome until you get hurt. :|
(I learned my lesson about git-rebase.)

Comment: I'm sorry @ANeves. I wasn't been correct in question (now fixed): i haven't f1 and f3 branches any more.